Can associativity of elliptic curve group law be verified by hand?
On p.15 of Silverman's Rational Points on Elliptic Curves, after sketching the proof of the associativity law of point addition on an elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ via Bezout's theorem, the author says it can also be verified directly using the explicit formula $(x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2)=(x_3,y_3)$, where
$$x_3=\left(\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}\right)^2-a-x_1-x_2$$
and $y_3$ can be calculated from $x_3$. On p.27 he says it would take just "a few days" to do this. Has anyone actually done this by hand (I tried and gave up after half an hour)? I'm happy with just verifying the "generic case" and then appealing to continuity. I found several papers that verify associativity using computer algebra system, so presumably it's not practical for human. But as we know, 19th century people were really good at computation...

See Andrew Sutherland's code : https://cocalc.com/share/public_paths/a113e25fbea48a4d5c8076a60cc7f0ec90ee065c

A recent paper by Sander Zwegers derives a clever and elementary proof of associativity.  He was able to show that the formula for the coordinates of the point $(P_1+P_2)+P_3$ is symmetric in $P_1$ and $P_3$, and associativity easily follows. Here is the formula found by Zwegers. Suppose that none of the three points is the identity, and write $P_1=(x_1,y_1)$, $P_2=(x_2,y_2)$, $P_3=(x_3,y_3)$, $(P_1+P_2)+P_3=(x_4,y_4)$.
We make the assumption that the points are in "general position", meaning that there are no relationships such as $P_1=-P_2$ or $P_1+P_2=P_3$ or any other (and in the case that the field is $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ this is  true for a dense set of points).
For distinct points $P$, $Q$, define
$\alpha(P,Q)$ to be the slope of the line through $P$ and $Q$, and then define
$$c_1=\frac{x_1\alpha(P_2,P_3)-x_3\alpha(P_1,P_2)}{x_1-x_3}$$
$$c_2=\frac{\alpha(P_1,P_2)-\alpha(P_2,P_3)}{x_1-x_3}.$$
Then the coordinates $(x_4,y_4)$ are given by
$$x_4=-x_1+x_2-x_3+\frac{1}{c_2^2}-\frac{2c_1}{c_2},$$
$$y_4=-y_2-(x_4-x_2)(c_1+c_2x_4).$$
The proof is just elementary algebra and is fairly simple.
It's easy to check that the formulas are unchanged if we switch $P_1$ and $P_3$.
This proves associativity when the field is $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, and the points are in general position. To prove it for generic points $P_1$, $P_2$, $P_3$ (in $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$), we can use a limit argument, because the group law is continuous in the usual topology. If associativity holds for a dense set of points, it will hold for all points.
Finally, to prove it for general fields, we use the following argument: (that I found in these notes): the equations defining associativity can be reduced to polynomial equations where the variables are the coordinates of the three points. So associativity can be phrased by saying that certain polynomials in several variables are zero when we substitute a dense set of real or complex values for the variables. But this means that the polynomials must be identically zero, so they will be zero also when we substitute values from any field.

COMMENT. -Lamé's theorem (of the ninth point) is one of those results of classical geometry (19th century) that amaze with its refined perception. It is practically impossible to illustrate this theorem with a figure, unless the cubic is deformed very unrealistically.
Theorem. - If three straight lines  $L_A,L_B,L_C$   cut an elliptical cubic at the points $A_1,A_2,A_3 , B_1,B_2,B_3, C_1,C_2,C_3$ and if the points $A_1,B_1,C_1$ and $A_2,B_2,C_2$ are collinear, then points $A_3,B_3,C_3$ are also collinear (see at figure 1).
You have to show that if $P, Q, R$ are three points of the elliptic cubic then $P+Q+R$ is well defined (and so will be consequently with $P_1+\cdots+P_n$ that it is the associativity).
Try to apply Lamé’s theorem keeping into account that the point at infinity is the neutral element zero of the group and that
$$\begin{cases}P,Q\text { and}-(P+Q)\text { are collinear }\\P,R\text { and}-(P+R)\text { are collinear }\\R,-R\text { and } 0\text { are collinear }\\-Q,Q\text { and } 0\text { are collinear }\end{cases}$$
(Try to guide yourself with figure 2). I hope this comment is of some use to you.


This seems like the same geometric proof I mention in my question. I'm more interested in an algebraic proof using the explicit formula.

If Silverman tells you that you would need "a few days" to accomplish your goal, then you should believe him so as not to try to achieve something that is impossible. The brief comment I gave you about Lamé's theorem wanted to warn you about this. The expressions that can be achieved from a single point on an elliptic curve are generally infinite and grow very quickly (suite)

If you try, for example,  to show directly that $\sqrt[3]5+\sqrt[7]2$ is algebraic over $Q$ you won't be able to either, but you know that the sum of two algebraics is algebraic so you already know the result through another quick way. It is better that you abandon your purpose and continue studying this difficult and fascinating topic of elliptic curves.
